# what is a good way to model pasta or noodles?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Does anyone have any good methods or tips on how to model pasta or noodles?  I'm modeling a bowl of ramen.  I tried creating a noodle from a curve, converted to a mesh, and used the cloth modifier with collision on the bowl.  It didn't turn out too bad at all but they just never settle in the form or composition I'm looking for.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated!! :D

Comment: You should add a picture of what you are looking for. Because that way you wrote your question it can be anything…

Comment: I think you can ask the one and only pasta master here or on the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm). see http://pasta.duarteramos.pt/#Home:Home%20%5B%5BAll%20Pasta%5D%5D But please add an example of what you achieved so we can know what's the baseline here